# How to populate a listview to another activity

Tags: android

I want to transfer a listView from MainActivity to ResultActivity. Below my code on ResultActivity

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String LOG_TAG = ResultActivity.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    TextView tv1 = (Textiew) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ListView listviewProionta = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewProiontaResult);       


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String s_Papageorgiou = intent.getStringExtra("message1");
    String s_Papadopoulos = intent.getStringExtra("message2");
    Serializable arrayList = intent.getSerializableExtra("arrayList");

    ArrayList<Proion> proiontaList = (ArrayList<Proion>) arrayList;


    ProiontaAdapter proiontaAdapter = new ProiontaAdapter(this, proiontaList);

    proiontaAdapter.addAll(proiontaList);

    listviewProionta.setAdapter(proiontaAdapter);



}
}
```

Below the ProiontaAdapter class

```
public class ProiontaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Proion> {

public static final String LOG_TAG = ProiontaAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


public ProiontaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Proion> proionta) {
    super(context, 0, proionta);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Proion proion = getItem(position);

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_proion_item2, parent, false);
    }

    TextView nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proion2);
    TextView posotitaView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posotita2);
    TextView prosforaView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prosfora2);
    TextView monadametrisisView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.monadaMetrisis2);

    //getQuantity
    int quantitie = proion.getQuantity();

    //τοποθετώ name σε View
    nameView.setText(proion.getName());

    //τοποθετώ ποσότητα σε View
    posotitaView.setText(String.valueOf(quantitie));

    //τοποθετώ μονάδα μετρησης σε  View
    monadametrisisView.setText(String.valueOf(proion.getMonada_metrisis()));

    //τοποθετώ προσφορά σε View
    prosforaView.setText(proion.prosfora());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

And below the activity_result.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/totalLayout"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="tsakiris.com.smproject2.ResultActivity">

    //Textview
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/papageorgiou_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.62"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Παπαγεωργιου"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    //Textview
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/papadopoulos_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20px">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="150px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.62"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingTop="20px"
            android:text="Παπαδόπουλος"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.62"
            android:text="Button"/>

    //Listview
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewProiontaResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I use an intent from MainActivity to ResultActivity and i successfully transfer the arrayList of Proion objects  that i want from MainActivity to ResultActivity, and also i get proiontaList. Its ok up to there.  But the Listview doesnt get  populated on the ResultActivity. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: You cannot transfer a **view** from one activity to another. You can only send **data**. It appears that you have the right idea doing this with an Intent. You should use the Android Studio debugger to check that the `proiontaList` contains the expected data. If so, then set a breakpoint in your adapter's `getView()` method to see if it is executed.

Comment: p.s. Since you are programming in Java, you should include the class which contains each code snippet. In particular, add the `class ProiontaAdapter extends ???` line and the appropriate braces.

Comment: yes i ommited to show the line public class ProiontaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Proion>

Comment: Please edit your question to include that as well as the appropriate braces. You should also fix indentation as appropriate.

Comment: But the adapter seems to be working proprely. I use an instance of the adapter in MainActivity to populate the listview there. Any other idea?

Comment: My suggestions about adding the class declaration are to help improve your question so that it is more clear and also more helpful for future readers. My suggestions to help you figure out the problem are in my first comment. Please read it.